# Wrapping html tag bound UI Components in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-components

I'm creating a "wrapper" library around Angular Material UI for my application, as described in this article: [Should you wrap your UI components article](https://medium.com/@TimHolzherr/should-you-wrap-your-ui-component-library-42dfc41df828)

Pretty much the idea is to have a little abstraction level which would make it easier to write standard UI functionality, hide details of underlying implementation from UI developers and make it possible to easily refactor large chunks of application UX without going through much code.

One thing I'm stuck with is trying to wrap components which don't have its own dedicated tag but bind to existing HTML tag, for example `MatButton` component which binds to `<button mat-button>`

I want to create a corresponding component `<button my-button>` which should behave exactly as `<button mat-button mat-primary mat-raised-button>`. This was quite trivial in Angular 1, but for new Angular I'm completely lost... Please help!

Here is a code example: [Stack Blitz Button Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-responsive-buttons-yavvnw?file=app%2Fbutton.component.ts)

Comment: For doing that you can use "Attribute Directives":  https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#apply-the-attribute-directive

Comment: No, unfortunately attribute directives can't dynamically bind components: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260996/dynamically-bind-model-and-template-to-at-dom-node-in-angular-2

Comment: That was my first thought as well and that's how I would do it in Angular 1...

Comment: If you are going to use ivy as compiler you can use HOCs to provide that. An [example](https://blog.nrwl.io/metaprogramming-higher-order-components-and-mixins-with-angular-ivy-75748fcbc310)

Answer (score 4):

Created a forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-responsive-buttons-embedded-view?file=app/button.component.ts) for you.
Here I am using `ViewContainerRef` to fully replace component's initial html tag and create new root view with our material button.
Be careful because in this case change detection becomes manual.

Comment: Thank you, this is a step in the right direction - however I would much prefer to have something like material button does itself in https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button/button.html where they embed <button> tag into <ng-content> rather than having it on the template explicitly - because in this case I don't just need to have manual change detection but also duplicate all callbacks like (click) on that tag... Anyway if there are no more takers I'll assign bounty to you, thanks.